# How did people say “I have to go to the bathroom” before the bathroom and pipes were common?

Tags: middle-ages, everyday-life

I am writing a story in a medieval world of fantasy, and today a little girl is trapped next to her brother in a hole.

The girl has to go to the bathroom, but I do not know how to be someone that age and at that time I would tell a rescuer that she needs to go to the bathroom.

Is there any difference to how it is today? Is there something I should avoid?

Comment: Just a guess, would probably depend on class. An upper class girl might say she needed a chamber pot. A peasant would probably just say she needed to piss! They weren't so coy in those days! ;-)

Comment: This might be more suitable for Linguistics, Writing or English Language. Anyway, why not "I have to pee/poo"?

Comment: TheHonRose, Vincenzo Oliva, maybe not then, but my readers surely do now.

Comment: Since its fantasy, you can just make up something. There's gotta be some universe-appropriate version of "drain the dragon" you could come up with.

Comment: @T.E.D. Alternatively, "Feed the Kracken"  as the case may be.  um, "Feed the wolves" in more northerly climes

Comment: Medieval world? She might say she has to visit the latrine. Or "alleviate herself".

Comment: "I need a moment" always works!

Comment: The term "*water closet*", along with its abbreviation "WC" occasionally pronounced "way-say", is an old common synonym for the bathroom. It may be of European origin as I first learned it from my father, who grew up in the Netherlands.

Comment: In the old time rural USA people would probably say they had to go to the outhouse, which is where the latrine would be.  Which could be very uncomfortable in bad whether.  There were probably also outhouses in backyards in cities.  Medieval Europeans who had similar arrangements would probably mention the outhouse or whatever they called it.  So for historic realism in your medieval fantasy, find out about the facilities in Medieval manor houses, peasant households, town houses, monasteries, etc.

Comment: _I have to go in the bushes_?

Comment: "Mind your feet"? Really though, unless she's part of some wealthy family, the idea of waiting until she could get to a proper toilet is unlikely. Depending on the hole, she's more likely to dig a smaller hole to pee in rather than pee directly onto the ground.

Comment: The term "bathroom", when used for the location where someone goes to relieve themselves is generally regarded as an American term. Other English speaking countries, have until recently used terms such as a water closet (or WC), or simply "the toilet". In such countries, the bathroom is where people go to wash/bathe/shower & usually bathrooms in such countries do not contain toilets (bowels) & cisterns. For whatever reason, most of the Americans I've met tend to regard the term "toilet" as being vulgar.

Comment: @Fred - UK bathrooms do contain a toilet/lavatory, as well as a bath/shower/basin. Strangely, "toilet" was always thought impossibly coy in my youth - the upper classes called it the "lavatory". The same tends to apply nowadays to "I need the bathroom." Most Brits would say "loo", except, eg, in an hotel, where it would be Ladies or Gents.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As with today, there were many different terms used in medieval times and what a little girl would have said would have depended very much on her upbringing / social background and perhaps the immediate environment in which she found herself.

She could just use the verb ***piss*** as it was not considered vulgar [until circa. 1760](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=IAjyQdFwh4UC&pg=PA864&lpg=PA864&dq=make%20water%20medieval%20slang%20for%20pissing&source=bl&ots=_3MwjHtJ4G&sig=FNhv1cOaHw_9sIrQ7B9fmGc4vp0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ1uiwnYDcAhVHIMAKHYBTBqQQ6AEIVTAD#v=onepage&q=make%20water%20medieval%20slang%20for%20pissing&f=false). Here are a few possibilities (nouns) where she could ***go*** (this is one verb used with at least some of the nouns below):

- [**go to siege**](https://e-royalty.com/top-stories/7-medieval-phrases-to-spice-up-your-next-conversation/), presumably related to the French *siege*, meaning 'seat', and probably used by those of high social standing [such as knights](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/mark-forsyth/weird-phrases_b_4018105.html). The use of *siege* is also mentioned in Christopher Coredon & Ann Williams, [*A Dictionary of Medieval Terms and Phrases*](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/A_Dictionary_of_Medieval_Terms_and_Phras.html?id=x9ouGQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)).
- **[privy](http://www.medievalists.net/2014/09/public-toilets-middle-ages/)**, as in "it would be more decent to **go to the common privies** of the city", from an incident in 1307 when a king's groom was confronted by two Londoners for urinating on a side street. The use of *privy* dates back to around 1225. The Dominican monk Felix Faber of Ulm, writing about his travels as a pilgrim between 1480 and 1483, advises fellow pilgrims to "**go to the privies** three or four times every day" (cited in *[The Porcelain God: A Social History of the Toilet](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/The_Porcelain_God.html?id=Boy6AAAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)* by Julie L. Horan). [John Lydgate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Lydgate), in *Pilgrimage of the Life of Man* (translated from the French c.1475), mentions "**[goyng to pryvee](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=149473113&egdisplay=open&egs=149488231)**".
- she might ask for a [**chambre coi**](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/A_Dictionary_of_Medieval_Terms_and_Phras.html?id=x9ouGQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) (chamber pot) (OFr. coi < L quietus = quiet, at rest). Chamber pots were also known as [originals, jerrys](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/The_Porcelain_God.html?id=Boy6AAAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) and [pisse-pots](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=143338249&egdisplay=open&egs=143339105).

[image]

*[Medieval Chamber Pot (1300-1500)](http://www.historyofyork.org.uk/themes/medieval/medieval-chamber-pot), Yorkshire Museum collection*

- **[easement room](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/A_Dictionary_of_Medieval_Terms_and_Phras.html?id=x9ouGQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)** or **chamber of easement**, a euphemism of the time.
- **[longaigne](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/A_Dictionary_of_Medieval_Terms_and_Phras.html?id=x9ouGQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)** (in a castle), "usually opening directly into a ditch
  below...being always open to the outside, they were a weak point of
  defence during a siege"
- **[rere-dorter](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/A_Dictionary_of_Medieval_Terms_and_Phras.html?id=x9ouGQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)**, meaning literally 'at the rear of the dormitory' in, for example, a monastery. It was sometimes referred to as *necessarium* (the necessary).
- **[necessary house](https://books.google.com.ph/books?redir_esc=y&id=-WLlAgAAQBAJ&q=privies#v=snippet&q=privies&f=false)** (nidhus). One such was built by Henry I's wife Matilda; it emptied into the Thames.
- **[garderobe](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/A_Dictionary_of_Medieval_Terms_and_Phras.html?id=x9ouGQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)**, "small room for keeping robes and clothing. Later, it was used euphemistically of a privy or latrine; these were sometimes built into a thick wall, directly above a moat."
- **[pissyngholes](https://books.google.com.ph/books?redir_esc=y&id=-WLlAgAAQBAJ&q=privies#v=onepage&q=pissyngholes&f=false)**, a colloquialism cited with reference to toilets in York over the Ouse bridge.
- **[gong-hus](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/A_Dictionary_of_Medieval_Terms_and_Phras.html?id=x9ouGQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)** "Lit. ‘going-house’". The use of the words *[gong](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2015/11/12/words-for-toilet/)* and *gang* date back to at least the high middle ages with one meaning being *[go](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gong#Etymology_1)* (verb) and *[a going](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gong#Etymology_1)* (noun). Chaucer mentions [**a commune gong**](https://books.google.com.ph/books?redir_esc=y&id=-WLlAgAAQBAJ&q=privies#v=snippet&q=gong&f=false) in the Canterbury Tales. The Anglo-Saxons had many variants using *gong* or *gang*:

> a gangpytt (‘going-pit’), gangeen (‘going place’), gangsetl
>   (‘going-seat’), and gangtun (‘going-yard’), or an utgang (‘outgoing’),
>   forthgang, and earsgang (‘arse-going’).

*Source: David Crystal, '[Words in Time and Place: Exploring Language Through the Historical Thesaurus of the Oxford English Dictionary](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=hbw8BAAAQBAJ&dq=privy%201225&source=gbs_navlinks_s)' (2014)*

- **[chamber foreign](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=hbw8BAAAQBAJ&dq=privy%201225&source=gbs_navlinks_s)**. "This is foreign in the sense of ‘out of doors’. Within a few
  years of its first recorded usage, we see it abbreviated to
  foreign (1303). Chaucer, in The Legend of Good Women
  (c.1385), describes a tower that ‘was joining in the wall to a
  foreign’ (line 1962, in the story of Ariadne)."

Unless Shakespeare (writing in the early modern period) used an anachronism, *water* was used in the middle ages to refer to urine; this appears in his play [Henry IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_IV,_Part_1) (d. 1413). [Jonathan Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Swift) (1667 - 1745) is cited by Samuel Johnson, "Go to bed, after you have made water", but I can't confirm if this was used in medieval times.

Comment: Wow, I learn a lot today!!!